# Swift - Custom View with xib file, IBOutlet is nil

Tags: swift, xcode, custom-controls, iboutlet

I have a custom button designed using xib file like this: 
[image]

and I connect it to my storyboard like this:

[image]

but when I run the app, I got runtime error complaining that IBOutlet ivRightIcon is nil

```
@IBInspectable var rightIcon: UIImage? = nil{
    didSet{
            ivRightIcon.image = rightIcon
        }
    }
}
```

My outlet is connected in xib file correctly
I'm using Swift 3 and xCode 8.2.1
Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve this. I should set the View class as UIButton and File's Owner as my custom button class

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to connect your xib with file responder and assign class to file responder instead of view. then connect IBOutlet of xib to the class.

Comment: You must be referring to *File's Owner*

Answer (score 0):

I solved that error by modifying the outlets values in `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`. This way the outlets is fully loaded when accessed.